# Questions regarding inserting relation when using Upsert in Laravel

Tags: laravel, upsert

At hourly basis I have a schedule running a job that connects to my bank and fetches my bank transactions.

Unfortunately, my bank's API return transactions without any transaction IDs, and also transaction details will change over time, example:

Once paying for something the transaction amount is only reserved from the account, not actually withdrawn. So if I pay $100, the amount is withdrawn from my account and a transaction item is created with the following details:

```
{
    "amount": {
        "amount": -100,
        "currencyCode": "USD"
    },
    "accountingDate": "2021-01-19",
    "description": "PAYMENT",
    "transactionCode": "123",
    "transactionType": null
}
```

And a few hours later, or even maybe up to a day, this transaction entry in the API will have changed to something like:

```
{
    "amount": {
        "amount": -100,
        "currencyCode": "USD"
    },
    "accountingDate": "2021-01-19",
    "description": "WALMART",
    "transactionCode": "R_123",
    "transactionType": "Purchase"
}
```

In this case it is three different values being changed: `description`, `transactionCode` and `transactionType`.

- The `description` field gets updated with details of the vendor or receiver of the money.
- The `transactionCode` field references the bank's transaction categorization (which is not public), but when the code is prefixed with `R_` it means it's withdrawn and accounted.
- The `transactionType` field is updated with information in regards of the type of transaction (not neccessary in correlation with the `transactionCode` field). Examples are "Visa", "Purchase", "Bill payment", "Fees", "Transfer between own accounts" etc.

So to handle this in my application I use the `upsert` function where I basically check for changes in any of the fields from the API which in 99% of the cases do work.

But; I thought I would extract the `transactionCode` values to a separate table, using them as categories in my own app. What is the quickest and easiest way to extract the data (regardless of its `R_` prefix) with doing lots of queries to check the database for already existing value?

I'm thinking of something like for each transaction:

1. Get `transactionCode` value
2. Strip the `R_` prefix
3. Check if transaction code exists in database
4. Insert if not
5. Create relation for transaction

But for several hundred transactions at a time it might not be suitable to do a check for each transaction code value. Would it make more sense to fetch all transaction codes before looping the transactions and then create the relations afterwards?

And also, how do I insert relation when using `upsert`?